# split name into more columns with R

Tags: r, split, multiple-columns

I have a column with the following names:
"John Doe", "Susie R. Que", "joe & Jill smith", "sam and karen hill"

I want the output to look like:
first name: John, susie R., Joe & Jill, sam and karen
last name: doe, que, smith, hill

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on Stack Overflow please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and if not already done, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) read.table** Assuming the input `Names` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end replace the last space with semicolon and read that in using `read.table`.  No packages are used.

```
read.table(text = sub("(.*) ", "\\1;", Names$name), sep = ";", as.is = TRUE,
 col.names = c("First", "Last"))
```

giving:

```
          First  Last
1          John   Doe
2      Susie R.   Que
3    joe & Jill smith
4 sam and karen  hill
```

**2) strcapture** Another base R solution can be based on `strcapture`.  The first capture group in the regular expression captures everything up to but not including the last space and the second capture group captures everything after the last space.

```
strcapture("(.*) (.*)", Names$name, list(First = character(0), Last = character(0)))
```

**3) separate** Another possibility is similar to (1) but uses `separate` in the tidyr package instead of `read.table`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

Names %>%
  mutate(name = sub("(.*) ", "\\1;", name)) %>%
  separate(name, c("First", "Last"), sep = ";")
```

### Note

```
Names <- data.frame(name = c("John Doe", "Susie R. Que", "joe & Jill smith",
  "sam and karen hill"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: This worked great! Thank-you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gsub`

```
d <- c("John Doe", "Susie R. Que", "joe & Jill smith", "sam and karen hill")
gsub(pattern = '(.*)\\s.*',replacement = '\\1',x = d)
```